# Solve this system of equations ($3$ equations and $3$ variables)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$y - z = 20$$

$$z(x + 30) - xy = 840$$

$$x(y + z) = 30y$$

These are the three equations. I know that the answers are $x = 18$, $y = 60$, and $z = 40$, but whenever I try to solve for $z$ for my first number answer I end up with an unfactorable polynomial (something in the form of $30z^2 - 840z - 14400 = 0$) and when I try to solve for $x$ I keep ending up with it equal to $15$, which is not the right answer (ends up eventually like $1680x = 25200$). I'm going to attempt solving for $y$ next, but with my lack of luck so far I doubt I'll get the answer I want. What's the most efficient format to solving this system of equations with $3$ variables?

Comment: It should be noted that $30z^2-840z-14400=0$ is 1) a correct conclusion to reach, 2) can be simplified to $z^2-28z-480=0$, and 3) can be factored (as can any other quadratic, cubic, or quartic equation), in particular by using the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to correctly give the two possibilities, $z=-12$ or $z=40$.

Answer (score 2):

**tldr:** use given information to reduce the number of equations and unknowns.

---

The first step I would do in any problem like this is to try to reduce the number of equations and variables (if at all possible).

From the first equation, $y-z=20$, this tells us that we have a way of replacing each occurrence of $z$ with $y-20$.  We go ahead and make that substitution to have a system of two equations and two unknowns:

$$\begin{cases}(y-20)(x+30)-xy = 840\\ x(y+(y-20))=30y\end{cases}$$

Simplifying these a little we arrive at:

$$\begin{cases}30y-20x=1440\\2xy-20x=30y\end{cases}$$

Now, we try to reduce the number of variables further.  The top remaining equation can handle that:  It says that $30y-20x=1440$.  By isolating $y$, this means: $y=\frac{2x+144}{3}$.

Replacing this new expression for $y$ into the only remaining equation, we have then a single equation in a single variable, which can be solved.

$$2x(\frac{2x+144}{3})-20x=30(\frac{2x+144}{3})$$

Which after some simplifications brings you to:

$$4x^2+288x-60x=60x+4320$$

and further simplification to:

$$x^2+42x-1080=0$$

This is a quadratic equation in one variable and can be solved using various methods.  You will in particular find that there are two possible solutions: $x=-60$ or $x=18$.  At the moment, both seem equally plausible, so we will keep hold of both.  (For information on factoring quadratics, see [Quadratic Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).  For information on factoring arbitrary cubics or quartics, try to identify a factor by inspection to reduce it to the problem of factoring a quadratic, or see [Cardano's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function) and [Solving a quartic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation), though hopefully you will need to use neither of these unwieldy methods)

With this new knowledge of what $x$ can be, we backtrack.  Remembering that $y=\frac{2x+144}{3}$, by plugging in the value for $x$ this means that when $x=-60$ that $y=8$, or when $x=18$ that $y=60$.

Now armed with this final piece of information, we can backtrack further to find $z$.  Remembering that $z=y-20$, by plugging in the value for $y$, this means that when $x=-60$ and $y=8$ that $z=-12$, or when $x=18$ and $y=60$ that $z=40$.

We can now try to plug in these values to test to see if they each work:

Testing $(-60,8,-12)$:

$$\begin{cases} (8)-(-12)=20 \color{green}{\checkmark}\\
(-12)(-60+30)-(-60)(8)=840\color{green}{\checkmark}\\
(-60)(8-12) = 30(8)\color{green}{\checkmark}\end{cases}$$

Testing $(18,60,40)$:

$$\begin{cases} 60-40=20\color{green}{\checkmark}\\
40(18+30)-18\cdot 60=840\color{green}{\checkmark}\\
18(60+40)=30\cdot 60 \color{green}{\checkmark}\end{cases}$$

Thus, both $(-60,8,-12)$ and $(18,60,40)$ are solutions to this system of equations.  One can see as well (via the method) that there are no *other* solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you have $$y-z = 20, 30z-x(y-z) =840\to 30z-20x = 840\to 3z-2x=84, xy + xz=30y.$$

keeping $z$ and solving for $x, y$ we have $$y = 20+z, x= (3z-84)/2.\tag 1$$ subbing in $xy + xz=30y$ gives $$(3z-84)(20+z)/2+ (3z-84)z/2=30(20+z)\to\\(3z-84)(10+z)= 3z^2-54z-840= 600+30z$$ we end with the quadratic 
$$0=z^2-28z-480 =(z-40)(z+12)$$ therefore the roots are $$z = 40, -12 $$ and the corresponding $x,y$ are found from $(1).$

Answer (score 0):

$$y - z = 20$$

$$z(x + 30) - xy = 840$$

$$x(y + z) = 30y$$

From the first equation, we get that $y = z + 20$

Substituting this into the second equation, we get

$$z(x+30)-x(z+20) = 840 \rightarrow 30z - 20x = 840 \rightarrow 3z-2x=84 \rightarrow x = \frac{3z-84}{2}$$

Now, substituting this into the third equation, we get

$$x((z+20)+z) = 30(z+20) \rightarrow 2xz+20x = 30z+600 \rightarrow$$

$$2\cdot\frac{3z-84}{2}\cdot z+20\cdot\frac{3z-84}{2} = 30z+600 \rightarrow 3z^2-84z-1440 = 0 \rightarrow z^2-28z-480 = 0 \rightarrow (z-14)^2 = 676 \rightarrow z = 14 \pm 26 \rightarrow z = 40 \text{ or } -12$$

We test $z = 40$, which leads to $y = 60$ and $x = 18$.

We also test $z = -12$, and get $y = 8$ and $x = -60$.

Both of these sets of solutions work when we plug them into the system of equations again, so I'm not sure why only the first answer is considered correct... is there some kind of a requirement like $x,y,z \ge 0$?

Anyways, I get two answers and they are $$(x,y,z) = (18,60,40) \text{ or } (-60,8,-12)$$

---

As for how to solve systems of equations like this, it's really a bit of an intuition that you develop through practice, but I can go through my thought process a bit.

1. I looked at the three equations and decided that the first equation, since it only deals with $2$ variables instead of $3$, is the easiest one to start with.
2. I used it to express $y$ in terms of $z$ (you can express $z$ in terms of $y$ as well, I simply prefer having $y$ by itself because it comes before $z$ in the alphabet :P) and then plug in the expression for $y$ into the second equation. I did this because now there are $xz$ terms that cancel each other out and the number terms make it seem like the $10$s will cancel out to make the equation nicer (fortunately, in this case, it did, but don't always take it for granted).
3. Then once we got $z$ and $x$ in their own linear equation, I decided to express $x$ in terms of $z$ instead of the other way because then I can have a $2$ in the denominator which cancels out nicely with both the $(2z+20)$ term on the left side and the $30$ on the right hand side.
4. I plug in the expression for $x$, rearrange the terms and get a quadratic equation for $z$, solve it, and then plug it back in to find the answers.